# Problem to get integer values for Protege DataProperty from Excel using Cellfie

Tags: excel, protege, manchester-syntax

I am using Cellfie plug-in for Protégé to create ontological individuals from an Excel database of scientific articles. I face a problem when I try to assign an integer value to a property 'has interger value' which range is xsd:integer. In fact, the property is being assigned but without the ^^xsd:integer type specification, so the reasoner fail beacause those values are not recognized as integers. I am using this Manchester Syntax code, which is not causing any error, but the values given to the properties are not declared as integers inside the Protégé ontology:

Individual: @B*

Types: 'Publication year'

Facts: 'has integer value' @B*(xsd:integer)

The column B of the Excel is full of integer numbers (years). If I try using xsd:string, the properties have the correct type declaration ^^xsd:string, but if I try to use xsd:integer the axioms are created ignoring the type declaration.

Comment: Also if I try Facts: 'has integer value' @B*(xsd:double) it does include the type declaration xsd:double correctly, and the year numbers are assigned to the properties as doubles .So it is quite frustrating why it seems that integer type is the only one ignored.

Comment: I'm wondering if xsd:int works?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. `xsd:integer` works well for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually it was recognized as an integer even if the declaration did not appear explicitly, the reasoning error was pointing to another related issue, but apparently it was not a problem of Cellfie.